# Why useState is not changing in event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

When I change state in my school event listener is not changing inside, like I have constantly setting isScrollable to true, but it should set only one time , when scroll is happens

````
  const [isScrollable, setIsScrollable] = useState(false);
  const scrollableDiv = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const current = scrollableDiv.current;

    const handleScroll = debounce(() => {
      if (!isScrollable) {
        console.log("setting");
        setIsScrollable(true);
      }
      //code...
    }, 16);

    if (current) {
      current.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }

    return () => {
      if (current) {
        current.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      }
    };
  }, []);```
````